# XML File Creation and Viola-Jones

Tags: xml, image-processing, machine-learning, detection, adaboost

I am trying to create an XML file to detect hand gestures as good and robust as that of haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml by Rainer Leinhart. So far, I have tried various training techniques such as the one posted in http://nayakamitarup.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-make-your-own-haar-trained-xml.html (took around a couple of hours to three days) and the one in http://note.sonots.com/edit.php?SciSoftware/haartraining (which takes around one week). Both did not generate a file that can successfully detect the corresponding hand. Have any of you tried these two ways of training an XML file and got successful results? I've also tried mailing the authors of the two sites, no luck still.

I have alse came across the article Robust Real-Time Face Detection by Paul Viola & Michael Jones (and one question posted here by Koji Ikehara entitled Viola Jones Experiments (training sets)), would any of you know how to normalize the sample images for the training? Has anyone came across any tool for this task?

I'm new here and I would appreciate any insights on this one. Thank you!

Comment: Calm down, at least split your question in two (as in, two separated questions in this site): hand gestures and face recognition. Also, "training a XML file" is a very weird expression, it simply doesn't make sense. To help you, first you have to improve your question. What were the steps to obtain data, train, and test ? Include relevant code, etc.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by: "Both did not generate a file that can successfully detect the corresponding hand". Are you saying the training doesn't finish? are you saying it segfaults? or a you saying you don't get the accuracy you're expecting?